# Forcing a DrawingVisual to redraw

Tags: wpf, drawingvisual

I'm trying to draw a random sqaure using the **DrawingVisual** class, and a "New Square" Button to replace the square with newly generated one.

I'm not able to figure out how to Force the **DrawingVisual** to redraw.

I'm not looking for alternative solution, I just want to know if it's possible to change a **DrawingVisual** after it's been instantiated

Here's my current Code:

```
     <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <local:RandomSquare Grid.Column="0" x:Name="randomSqare"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="New Square..." Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
```

Here's me trying the **InvalidateVisual** method

```
    public partial class SquareWindow : Window
    {
        public SquareWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            randomSqare.InvalidateVisual();
        }
    }
```

```
    public  class RandomSquare : UIElement
    {
        private DrawingVisual _visual;

        public RandomSquare()
        {
            _visual = GetRandomSquare();
        }

        private DrawingVisual GetRandomSquare()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int xy = rnd.Next(200);
            int size = rnd.Next(200);

            DrawingVisual visual = new DrawingVisual();

            using (DrawingContext context = visual.RenderOpen())
            {
                context.DrawRectangle(Brushes.AliceBlue, new Pen(Brushes.DarkBlue, 1), new Rect(xy, xy, size, size));
            }

            return visual;
        }

        protected override int VisualChildrenCount => 1;

        protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
        {
            return _visual;
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working because

```
randomSqare.InvalidateVisual();
```

does not magically call the `GetRandomSquare()` method.

That method is called only once when the RandomSquare element is created, i.e. during the `InitializeComponent()` call in the Window constructor.

---

You may instead draw into the DrawingContext that is passed to an overridden `OnRender` method:

```
public class RandomSquare : UIElement
{
    private readonly Random random = new Random();

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);

        int xy = random.Next(200);
        int size = random.Next(200);

        drawingContext.DrawRectangle(
            Brushes.AliceBlue,
            new Pen(Brushes.DarkBlue, 1),
            new Rect(xy, xy, size, size));
    }
}
```

---

When you want to use a DrawingVisual, you need to call `AddVisualChild` in its UIElement parent. You would also have to declare an explicit method for updating the DrawingVisual.

```
public class RandomSquare : UIElement
{
    private readonly DrawingVisual visual = new DrawingVisual();
    private readonly Random random = new Random();

    public RandomSquare()
    {
        AddVisualChild(visual);
    }

    protected override int VisualChildrenCount => 1;

    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index) => visual;

    public void Update()
    {
        int xy = random.Next(200);
        int size = random.Next(200);

        using (var drawingContext = visual.RenderOpen())
        {
            drawingContext.DrawRectangle(
                Brushes.AliceBlue,
                new Pen(Brushes.DarkBlue, 1),
                new Rect(xy, xy, size, size));
        }
    }
}
```